# Tail-recursive query string builder in F#

Tags: strings, f#

I have a situation where I'm generating a URL based on a set of query string parameters for use in an API. I know ahead of time that the values passed to this function are URL-safe and the tuples are complete, so I don't need to serialize the data or do data validation beyond just checking the length of the array.

This is a function where I'm generating a url from a `(string * string)[]`. I'm trying to avoid using mutable values, so this uses a tail-recursive function to build the string, with the URL being the "accumulator" value for the tail-recursion.

What I'm looking for is ways to better organize the function, flaws in the logic of the workflow, ways to make the function more readable, and just improvements in general.

```
let ComposeUrl (valuePairs:(string * string)[]) =
    let Composer (valuePairs:(string * string)[]) =
        let rec ComposerRec (valuePairs:(string * string)[]) (url:string) =
            match valuePairs.Length > 0 with
            | false -> url
            | true  -> 
                let tail = valuePairs.[1..valuePairs.Length - 1]
                let url = url + sprintf "&%s=%s" (fst valuePairs.[0]) (snd valuePairs.[0])
                ComposerRec tail url

        let tail = valuePairs.[1..valuePairs.Length - 1]
        let url = sprintf "?%s=%s" (fst valuePairs.[0]) (snd valuePairs.[0])
        ComposerRec tail url

    match valuePairs.Length > 0 with
    | false -> ""                     // No query string parameters
    | true  -> Composer valuePairs
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370346.aspx then http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876.aspx

Comment: Why do you use `match` on a boolean value instead of the much simpler `if`? You're not the first person I've seen who does that and I don't understand why do people do it.

Comment: @svick `match` is actually much easier for me to read. I used to use `if` if I just had a bool that I was testing against, but after becoming accustomed to using `match` for more complicated expressions, I decided to simplify my code by just using `match` everywhere.

Comment: @svick, also, I forgot to mention, `match` has built in coverage checking so it's much harder to screw up your workflows by using that instead of accidentally forgetting a case in a if/elif/else statement.

Comment: @KennethPosey Right, but I was talking about a simple `if then else`, like in your code, not more complicated situations.

Comment: @svick if I'm in a hurry I can and will forget the `else` part. `match` is another tool, among F#'s many tools, for helping me not be a dumbass.

Comment: @KennethPosey But something like `let x = if condition then 42` won't compile; you can't just forget `else`.

Comment: @svick I didn't know that because I never tried it or accidentally encountered it as a compiler error. Thanks again for the tip.

Comment: @svick I stumbled across this article, you might find it interesting concerning the discussion of the use of imperative style control statements vs pattern matching in functional design: http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/key-concepts/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daniel already suggested a much better way to write this, so I'm going to focus on details of your code:

```
let ComposeUrl (valuePairs:(string * string)[]) =
```

Why are you using an array here? As you must have noticed, they are pretty awkward to use with recursive functions and they don't fit well with functional programming in general.

---

```
let Composer (valuePairs:(string * string)[]) =
```

The name `Composer` sounds like it's an object, not a function. In general, function names should be verbs, and type names should be nouns.

Also, I don't really see the purpose of making this a separate function, you could include it into the main `ComposeUrl` function.

---

```
match valuePairs.Length > 0 with
    | false -> url
    | true  ->
```

Instead of pattern matching on a bool value, you can use `if`.

---

```
let tail = valuePairs.[1..valuePairs.Length - 1]
```

This means that every step of recursion is going to create a new array, this is very inefficient. Instead, you could use index that changes across the recursive invocations, while using a single array (or even better, use a `list`).

---

```
let url = url + sprintf "&%s=%s" (fst valuePairs.[0]) (snd valuePairs.[0])
```

I would use pattern matching to extract the key and the value, instead of `fst` and `snd`.

Also, why not make `url` part of the `sprintf`, to make the code more consistent?

And, while "mutating" variables like this is allowed by the language (you're not actually mutating it, you're creating a new variable with the same name, that hides the old one), I would generally avoid it to avoid confusion.

With these changes, the code would look like this:

```
let key, value = valuePairs.[0]
let newUrl = sprintf "%s&%s=%s" url key value
```

Also, concatenating strings like this is pretty inefficient (since every new string has to copy the whole previous string). One way to fix that would be to use `StringBuilder`, but that leads to using mutable data structures. A better way would be to put all the parts into a collection (ideally a `list`) and then join them using `String.Join()`.

---

```
        let tail = valuePairs.[1..valuePairs.Length - 1]
        let url = url + sprintf "&%s=%s" (fst valuePairs.[0]) (snd valuePairs.[0])
        ComposerRec tail url

let tail = valuePairs.[1..valuePairs.Length - 1]
let url = sprintf "?%s=%s" (fst valuePairs.[0]) (snd valuePairs.[0])
ComposerRec tail url
```

These two pieces of code are almost the same, except for a single character. That indicates you should figure out some way to avoid the repetition.

Answer (score 5):

As Mauricio suggested:

```
let ComposeUrl valuePairs = 
    if Seq.isEmpty valuePairs then ""
    else 
        let values = valuePairs |> Seq.map (fun (k, v) -> sprintf "%s=%s" k v)
        "?" + String.Join("&", values)
```